# Why does Rust export its whole standard library when building a DLL?

Tags: windows, dll, rust, ffi

I'm currently trying to write a dynamic library with Rust which will be loaded from a existing program. I need to export a few functions with specific names and calling conventions. Everything works, but as soon as I `use` anything from the standard library:

- The DLL size balloons to over 3MiB (Not exactly pretty, but I could live with that)
- The whole standard library gets exported from the DLL. Here is a lists with all exports: http://pastebin.com/LsG1u96C (5100 functions)

Am I missing some compiler switch?
I compile the following code with `rustc` without any options:

```
#![crate_type = "dylib"]
#![feature(std_misc)]

use std::ffi::CString;

#[link(name = "user32")]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
extern "stdcall" {
    fn MessageBoxA(hWnd: u32, lpText: *const i8, lpCaption: *const i8, uType: u32) -> u32;
}

#[no_mangle]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub unsafe extern "stdcall" fn _AddLuaState(lua_state_ptr: u32)
{
    let info_str = format!("Lua State Created: {}!", lua_state_ptr);
    let info_cstring = CString::new(info_str).unwrap();
    let caption = CString::new("Hello from my Rust Library!").unwrap();
    MessageBoxA(0, info_cstring.as_ptr(), caption.as_ptr(), 0);
}
```

`_AddLuaState@4` is the only function that should be exported.

This is on a Windows 8.1 machine with `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (522d09dfe 2015-02-19)` (x86)

Update: It looks like when compiling a dynamically linked file with `rustc -C prefer-dynamic`, the DLL size shrinks to 60kiB and there are only 3 extra exports (http://pastebin.com/G0AYZrpF) which all look quite reasonable. But I'd still prefer a statically linked library.

Comment: Does compiling with optimizations (`rustc -O`, `cargo build --release`) have any effect? Note that cargo puts release / non-release binaries in different directories.

Comment: Compiling with optimizations only shrinks the library by a few kiB, but has no other effect, the same happens with the cargo release build. But compiling with `-C prefer-dynamic` has an effect, please see my updated post.

Comment: Do `-C lto` or `-C link-args=--gc-sections` do anything? I've got no idea myself, just chucking it out there.

Comment: Link-Time-Optimization only works on static libraries, but I could get it to compile with `rustc -C link-args=-Wl,--gc-sections ldbg.rs`. Unfortunately, no effect here either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently the new crate type "cdylib" has been added that likely better fits your use-case. Replace the first line of your source file with:

```
#![crate_type = "cdylib"]
```

When using the Cargo package manager instead of directly calling `rustc` update `Cargo.toml` to contain the following lines:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

For more details have a look at [Rust pull request #33553](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/33553).

In my test it decreased the size of the following simple ["Hello World"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/ffi.html#calling-rust-code-from-c) DLL from 650k (dylib) down to 8k (cdylib). Also the number of exported symbols is decreased massively.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn hello_rust() -> *const u8 {
    "Hello, world!\0".as_ptr()
}
```